# Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp in hyperledger fabric

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

## Problem Summary

Hi!

I am new to hyperledger fabric. But, I have some experience with etherium blockchain development & linux.  I am trying to run the hyperledger fabric test-network under windows using docker for a project I'm working on with other people.  The larger project will use linux which is what motivated me to try to run fabric within an ubuntu container.

**My problem is the peer & orderer nodes exit immediately.** The cli node stays up and does not exit.

I have not been able to figure out the solution after reading many stackover flow answers  --- probably due to me being so new to fabric! Doh!

So, I'm unable to get the test-network up.  Getting the test network up and running is my first goal.

## Reproduction steps

### 1. Run my ubuntu container from windows & ssh into it

> docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --publish 2222:22 --publish 5951:5901 -it --volume C:\Users\foobar\GitHub\fabric-test:/fabric-test --name fabric-ubuntu ubuntu-vnc

(I can docker exec, ssh, and vnc into my ubuntu container.  So, it appears to be working fine.)

### 2. Bring the network down (from ubuntu)

**root@:/fabric/fabric-samples/test-network# ./network.sh down**

('down' completes successfully. So, I will not bore you with those messages.  :) )

### 3. Try to bring the network up (from ubuntu)

**root@:/fabric/fabric-samples/test-network# ./network.sh up**

*The 2 peers and orderer nodes exit immediately.*  See below "Exited".

> Creating network "fabric_test" with the default driver
> Creating volume "docker_orderer.example.com" with default driver
> Creating volume "docker_peer0.org1.example.com" with default driver
> Creating volume "docker_peer0.org2.example.com" with default driver
> Creating peer0.org1.example.com ... done Creating orderer.example.com    ...done
> Creating peer0.org2.example.com ... done Creating cli            ... done
> CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                               COMMAND    CREATED                  STATUS                              PORTS     NAMES
> 4d48c4d9660f   hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest     "/bin/bash"  Less than a second ago   Up Less than a second                        cli
> bcf192e5dc6a   hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"        2 seconds ago            **Exited (1) 1 second ago**        peer0.org1.example.com
> 962bc00c75f1   hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest   "orderer"                2 seconds ago            **Exited (2) 1 second ago**                                orderer.example.com
> d385a72a9f86   hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest     "peer node start"        2 seconds ago            **Exited (1) Less than a second ago**                                                       peer0.org2.example.com
> c887c64e473a   ubuntu-vnc                      "/bin/sh -c 'ls ;   …"   2 hours ago              Up 2 hours           0.0.0.0:2222->22/tcp, :::2222->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5951->5901/tcp, :::5951->5901/tcp   fabric-ubuntu

## docker app on windows shows the fabric nodes immediately exited:

[image]

## Error Messages from Docker Logs

From the docker application on windows, I am able to read the logs for peer0.org1* peer0.oerg2* orderer.* which give the following error messages.  I don't quite understand what this means, nor how to resolve the issues.

### peer0.org1.example.com log error message

> 2021-07-06 01:43:18.634 UTC [main] InitCmd -> **ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp: could not load a valid signer certificate from directory /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/signcerts: stat /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/signcerts: no such file or directory**

### peer0.org2.example.com log error message

> 2021-07-06 01:43:18.974 UTC [main] InitCmd -> **ERRO 001 Cannot run peer
> because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory
> /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp: could not load a valid signer certificate
> from directory /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/signcerts: stat
> /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/signcerts: no such file or directory**

### orderer.example.com log error message

...

> 2021-07-06 01:43:18.265 UTC [orderer.common.server] loadLocalMSP -> **PANI 003 Failed to get local msp config: could not load a valid signer certificate from directory /var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/signcerts: stat /var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/signcerts: no such file or directory
> panic: Failed to get local msp config: could not load a valid signer certificate from directory /var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/signcerts: stat /var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/signcerts: no such file or directory**
> ...

## Initial Questions

1. Does anyone know how to fix this?
2. Is anybody **successfully** running fabric within docker from windows?
3. Are there any tips on what I should look into or try to fix?

Thank you so much for any tips or advice on this.  It is appreciated.

Comment: Your problem is not a fabric problem but it's around understanding docker and how it's file systems and volume mounting works I would suggest investing some time studying this area if you continue down this path. But as you are on windows I wonder why you are bothering to run a docker container (as though it was a linux VM) when you might as well run a linux VM given that windows has to actually run a linux VM in order to run the docker container.

Comment: Dear david_k,I am looking to integrate this into a larger linux project using several technologies.  Yes, I have studied docker mounts and volumes and how to share filesystems amongst containers and the host system too.  I am also using volumes in the project now.  But, it's not clear to me what the issue is here, what is causing the error messages.

Comment: Peers and Orderers look for MSP configurations on the file system for example the orderer is looking at /var/hyperledger/orderer/msp for it's msp. So either that path does not exist within the orderer container or it doesn't contain the msp structure (which will be a set of subdirectories and files such as certificates/private keys/config files)